# Shared types in Java web service

Tags: java, jax-ws

I am building a web app that has a class called Product, which I'd like to be shared with a JAX-WS web service.

Basically, the web application sends an instance of the Product class to the webservice, the webservice makes some changes to its fields, and sends it back as a return type.

Is it possible to share the same type in Java this way? If not, what would be the approach to solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to package the common classes in a JAR file and add it to both clients and services, just like any other 3rd party JAR.

Comment: When I do this, and regenerate the WSDL for the web service, it still creates a proxy for Product for consumption in my web app. The WS method returns this proxied Product type, and I cannot cast it to a Product as my web app understands it...

Comment: Maybe you need to marshal and unmarshal another way.  Use JAXB and ask it to marshal the request into your Product object.  Or try a REST design - just pass a product ID to an HTTP GET request.